# jre 7u45 accessing to local file system

Tags: java, applet

On jre 7u45 ,applet faild to access to local file system with java.policy file any more.
signed jar with trusted CA can make success.
 This is a conclusion by testing.

Is there any official enunciation why java.policy is unavailable and signed jar with trusted CA is available for accessing to local file system?

Answer (score 0):

It's not official (but includes a link to the bug report Oracle says isn't there), but [this page](http://www.segal.org/java/SignedAppletTest/) may demonstrate the same problem. My signed applet code now refuses to run in _45 but will run unsigned with system policy file changes.